# Toggle showing a file (e.g. individual Cheatsheet)

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

To learn my mappings, I want to toggle an individual help (like e.g. a cheatsheet or so).

I don't know how to toggle showing of a window, is there any way or neat key map to toggle something like ":split ~/.vim_help" (with low height of the new window)? The purpose is to show my helpfile quickly, look for the command I can't remember and close (toggle) it then?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the shortest solution (nor the most elegant) but you can use it as a basis and tailor it to fit your needs:

```
" Create the mapping which will toggle the cheatsheet
nnoremap <F1> :call Cheatsheet()<CR>

function! Cheatsheet()
    " Save the z register
    let save_z = getreg('z')

    " Get the list of buffers in the z register
    redir @z
        silent filter /cheatsheet/ ls
    redir END

    " Get the result in a variable and restore the register
    let buff = getreg('z')
    call setreg('z', save_z)

    " The results has several lines, make it only one
    let buff = substitute(buff, '\n', '', 'g')

    " Get the status (hiden 'h' or not 'a') of the buffer
    let status = buff[match(buff, '[ah]')]

    " If the buffer is not hidden delete it, that will close the split
    if status == "a"
        let buffnumber = substitute(buff, '^\s*', '', '')[0]
        execute "bdelete " . buffnumber
    " Else open a split
    else
        vsplit ~/.cheatsheet
    endif
endfunction
```

These help topics might be helpful:

- [`:h :redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3aredir)
- [`:h :filter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3afilter)
- [`:h getreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getreg%28%29)
- [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29)
- [`:h :ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3als)